# Search for an object within an Array with a loop

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have an array of objects of my class:

```
HumorDiary[] note = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HumorDiary[]>(textt);
```

and I would like to look for an object inside it whose `int Giorno` property is equal to `DateTime.Now.Day`.

Here comes my doubt. If it doesn't find any objects, I would like it to increase `DateTime.Now.Day` by 1 and continually compare it to the `Giorno` property among the objects in the `Array`, as long as it doesn't find an object

```
foreach (HumorDiary diario in note)
{
    if (diario.Anno == DateTime.Now.Year)
    {                        
        if(diario.Giorno == DateTime.Now.Day)
        {
            HumorDiary hd = note.First();                                         
        }  
        else .........                       
    }               
}
```

Comment: Did you try with a while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `while` loop

```
HumorDiary hd = null;

var date = DateTime.Now.Day;

while(hd == null)
{
  foreach(...)

  if (hd == null) {
    date++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are declaring a `HumorDiary` variable inside the loop when you find a match, and trying to store a reference in it. But once the loop is complete, that variable will no longer exist and you will loose the reference.

Declare the `HumorDiary` variable outside the loop. Then inside the loop, if you find a match, store the reference in that variable, and break out of the loop. Else increase your intended value and continue with the loop -

```
HumorDiary[] note = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HumorDiary[]>(textt);

HumorDiary diary = null;

foreach (HumorDiary diario in note)
{
    if (diario.Anno == DateTime.Now.Year)
    {                        
        if(diario.Giorno == DateTime.Now.Day)
        {
            diary = diario;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            diario.Giorno++;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**
If by `"I would like it to increase DateTime.Now.Day by 1"` you meant to increase a value of a separate counter, and not the value of `Giorno`, then keep a counter outside the loop initialized with `DateTime.Now.Day` -

```
int count = DateTime.Now.Day;
```

then in the `else` block increase it's value -

```
else
{
    count++;
}
```